# Ref. Request -- Tautological Bundle over $G_{k,n}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, grassmannian

I'm interested right now to learn more about the tautological bundle over the Grassmann manifold $G_{k,n}(\mathbb{R})$, but I'm currently having trouble finding the appropriate texts to check out.  There's obviously [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautological_bundle), and I've also found a link to [John Milnor's *Characteristic Classes*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.448.869&rep=rep1&type=pdf), but I'm looking for something that's a little more pointed and directed (an article or two would be ideal).

My main interest in this stemmed from Milnor's [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_KqR5tBekQ&t=2139s) (go to 27:00) at Cornell where he described how this bundle space can be used as a classification space for tangent bundles.

Comment: I would give milnor stasheff another shot. The stuff about the grassmannians is really at the beginning, and really well written.

Answer (score 2):

Longer than an article, but still a good point of reference, is [Hirsch's "Differential Topology"](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4684-9449-5).  Chapter 4 on vector bundles includes classification theorems relating vector bundles to maps into Grassmannians.

Be warned, this book has *tons* of insidious errata.  A *partial* list has been compiled [here](https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/3779577764580/Hirscherrata.pdf).

Comment: Thank you!  This will be a great place for me to start.

Comment: The errata list can't be accessed without an account.